# Stream and process data based on timestamp values (Using Kafka and Spark Streaming)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'll try to simplify the problem I am trying to solve. I have an employee data stream which is being read from a JSON file and has the following schema:

```
StructType([ \
  StructField("timeStamp", TimestampType()),\
  StructField("emp_id", LongType()),\
  StructField("on_duty", LongType()) ])
# on_duty is an int boolean-> 0,1
```

Sample:

```
{"timeStamp": 1514765160, "emp_id": 12471979, "on_duty": 0}
{"timeStamp": 1514765161, "emp_id": 12472154, "on_duty": 1}
```

I would like to find out 2 things **every minute**, the total number of employees online and those NOT on duty and process it using structured spark streaming

This is per minute wrt. the timestamp, not the system time.

### Kafka Prod

```
_producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: 
                         json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
    
    # schedule.every(1).minutes.do(_producer.send(topic_name, value=( json.loads(json.dumps(dataDict))) ) )

    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding="utf16") as f: 

        for item in json_lines.reader(f):
            dataDict.update({'timeStamp':item['timestamp'],
                    'emp_id':item['emp_id'],
                    'on_duty':item['on_duty']})
            _producer.send(topic_name, value=( json.loads(json.dumps(dataDict))) )
            sleep(1)


# ^ Threading doesn't work BTW
```

### Spark streaming

```
emp_stream = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "emp_dstream") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
  .load() \
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") 

emp_data = emp_stream.select([
  get_json_object(col("value").cast("string"), "$.{}".format(c)).alias(c)
  for c in ["timeStamp", "emp_id", "on_duty"]])

# this query is a filler attempt which is not the end goal of the task 
query = emp_data.groupBy(["on_duty"]).count()

emp_data.writeStream \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .format("console") \
  .start() \
  .awaitTermination()
```

I am confused how to proceed. Do I make changes in the kafka producer or while processing the stream with spark? And how should I do that?

Would be grateful for any hints or help!

---

Update
Acc to @Srinivas solution

```
....----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|[1970-01-18 04:46:00, 1970-01-18 04:47:00]|1970-01-18 04:46:05|1070         |[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,....
```

---

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 40
-------------------------------------------
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|window                                    |timestamp          |Online_emp|Available_emp|
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|[2017-12-31 16:04:00, 2017-12-31 16:05:00]|2017-12-31 16:04:53|20            |12               |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:44|20            |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:47|4             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:27|20            |4                |
|[2017-12-31 16:03:00, 2017-12-31 16:04:00]|2017-12-31 16:03:10|4             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:25|4             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:42|12            |4                |
|[2017-12-31 16:03:00, 2017-12-31 16:04:00]|2017-12-31 16:03:20|4             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:03:00, 2017-12-31 16:04:00]|2017-12-31 16:03:49|4             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:03:00, 2017-12-31 16:04:00]|2017-12-31 16:03:44|12            |8                |
|[2017-12-31 16:02:00, 2017-12-31 16:03:00]|2017-12-31 16:02:19|8             |4                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:15|8             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:08|12            |4                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:50|8             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:04:00, 2017-12-31 16:05:00]|2017-12-31 16:04:27|16            |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:00:00, 2017-12-31 16:01:00]|2017-12-31 16:00:38|5             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:03:00, 2017-12-31 16:04:00]|2017-12-31 16:03:13|4             |4                |
|[2017-12-31 16:01:00, 2017-12-31 16:02:00]|2017-12-31 16:01:36|8             |4                |
|[2017-12-31 16:04:00, 2017-12-31 16:05:00]|2017-12-31 16:04:59|24            |4                |
|[2017-12-31 16:00:00, 2017-12-31 16:01:00]|2017-12-31 16:00:40|10            |0                |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
only showing top 20 rows

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 41
-------------------------------------------
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|window                                    |timestamp          |Online_emp|Available_emp|
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|[2017-12-31 16:04:00, 2017-12-31 16:05:00]|2017-12-31 16:04:53|20            |12               |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:44|20            |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:47|4             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:27|20            |4                |
|[2017-12-31 16:03:00, 2017-12-31 16:04:00]|2017-12-31 16:03:10|4             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:05:00, 2017-12-31 16:06:00]|2017-12-31 16:05:25|4             |0                |
```

---

Update 2

How to get output like this:

```
Time    Online_Emp  Available_Emp
2019-01-01 00:00:00 52  23
2019-01-01 00:01:00 58  19
2019-01-01 00:02:00 65  28
```

Comment: I am working on a similar problem myself. The documentation has got me a little confused.looking forward to finding out the solution

Comment: You mean am I sure? yes these are timestamp values. Should I change the longtype in the schema to timestamp

Comment: Now i understood, I am using timestamp in millies, but your timestamp is not in millies. you have to change ```.withColumn("timestamp",F.from_unixtime(F.col("timestamp") / 1000))``` with this ```.withColumn("timestamp",F.from_unixtime(F.col("timestamp")))```

Comment: yes it works but all the batches show the same info, repeatedly. It doesn't update with the kafka producer

Comment: i just did. Am i producing the kafka strea incorrectly by sendingit line by line and using sleep(1)

Comment: so if i have a large json file (~10GB) , do I use a different way to produce the kafka stream?

Comment: give me a little time to get back to you, the vm is acting a little slow

Comment: but wouldn't that output the whole file at once

Comment: yes because i wanted it to reflect real world stream

Comment: ok, may be you can test your logic for small stream of data and then apply same logic on big real world stream.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I have a simple query, when we process this data on spark , are we processing ALL the data that is on the console or batching it as it arrives? Cause maybe it processes all the data on it and that's why the same results everytime

Comment: It will process all data that is stored in kafka.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `window` function.

Sample data in Kafka

```
{"timeStamp": 1592669811475, "emp_id": 12471979, "on_duty": 0}
{"timeStamp": 1592669811475, "emp_id": 12472154, "on_duty": 1}
{"timeStamp": 1592669811475, "emp_id": 12471980, "on_duty": 0}
{"timeStamp": 1592669811475, "emp_id": 12472181, "on_duty": 1}
{"timeStamp": 1592669691475, "emp_id": 12471982, "on_duty": 0}
{"timeStamp": 1592669691475, "emp_id": 12472183, "on_duty": 1}
{"timeStamp": 1592669691475, "emp_id": 12471984, "on_duty": 0}
{"timeStamp": 1592669571475, "emp_id": 12472185, "on_duty": 1}
{"timeStamp": 1592669571475, "emp_id": 12472186, "on_duty": 1}
{"timeStamp": 1592669571475, "emp_id": 12472187, "on_duty": 0}
{"timeStamp": 1592669571475, "emp_id": 12472188, "on_duty": 1}
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12472185, "on_duty": 1}
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12472186, "on_duty": 1}
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12472187, "on_duty": 0}
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12472188, "on_duty": 1}
```

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, StructField, StructType, LongType, TimestampType
```

```
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("timeStamp", LongType()), \
    StructField("emp_id", LongType()), \
    StructField("on_duty", LongType())])
```

```
df = spark\
    .readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
    .option("subscribe","emp_dstream")\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
    .load()\
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")\
    .select(F.from_json(F.col("value"), schema).alias("value"))\
    .select(F.col("value.*"))\
    .withColumn("timestamp",F.from_unixtime(F.col("timestamp") / 1000))\
    .groupBy(F.window(F.col("timestamp"), "1 minutes"), F.col("timestamp"))\
    .agg(F.count(F.col("timeStamp")).alias("total_employees"),F.collect_list(F.col("on_duty")).alias("on_duty"),F.sum(F.when(F.col("on_duty") == 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))).alias("not_on_duty"))\
    .writeStream\
    .format("console")\
    .outputMode("complete")\
    .option("truncate", "false")\
    .start()\
    .awaitTermination()
```

Output

```
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+-----------+
|window                                       |timestamp          |total_employees|on_duty     |not_on_duty|
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+-----------+
|[2020-06-20 21:42:00.0,2020-06-20 21:43:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:42:51|4              |[1, 1, 0, 1]|1          |
|[2020-06-20 21:44:00.0,2020-06-20 21:45:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:44:51|3              |[0, 1, 0]   |2          |
|[2020-06-20 21:46:00.0,2020-06-20 21:47:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:46:51|4              |[0, 1, 0, 1]|2          |
|[2020-06-20 21:43:00.0,2020-06-20 21:44:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:43:51|4              |[1, 1, 0, 1]|1          |
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+-----------+
```

**Spark Batch**

```
spark \
    .read \
    .schema(schema) \
    .json("/tmp/data/emp_data.json") \
    .select(F.to_json(F.struct("*")).cast("string").alias("value")) \
    .write \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("topic", "emp_data") \
    .save()
```

**Spark Streaming**

```
spark \
    .readStream \
    .schema(schema) \
    .json("/tmp/data/emp_data.json") \
    .select(F.to_json(F.struct("*")).cast("string").alias("value")) \
    .writeStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("topic", "emp_data") \
    .start()
```

**JSON data in kafka**

```
/tmp/data> kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic emp_data
{"timeStamp":1592669811475,"emp_id":12471979,"on_duty":0}
{"timeStamp":1592669811475,"emp_id":12472154,"on_duty":1}
{"timeStamp":1592669811475,"emp_id":12471980,"on_duty":0}
{"timeStamp":1592669811475,"emp_id":12472181,"on_duty":1}
{"timeStamp":1592669691475,"emp_id":12471982,"on_duty":0}
{"timeStamp":1592669691475,"emp_id":12472183,"on_duty":1}
{"timeStamp":1592669691475,"emp_id":12471984,"on_duty":0}
{"timeStamp":1592669571475,"emp_id":12472185,"on_duty":1}
{"timeStamp":1592669571475,"emp_id":12472186,"on_duty":1}
{"timeStamp":1592669571475,"emp_id":12472187,"on_duty":0}
{"timeStamp":1592669571475,"emp_id":12472188,"on_duty":1}
{"timeStamp":1592669631475,"emp_id":12472185,"on_duty":1}
{"timeStamp":1592669631475,"emp_id":12472186,"on_duty":1}
{"timeStamp":1592669631475,"emp_id":12472187,"on_duty":0}
{"timeStamp":1592669631475,"emp_id":12472188,"on_duty":1}
^CProcessed a total of 15 messages
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but my console output is completely bizarre. I'll post a part of my console output in the question

Comment: it works with this code `datetime.fromtimestamp(item['timestamp']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` , the tiestamps are from 2017-2019

Comment: it greatly helped :) thank you. A small question that i wasn't able to find anywhere else, how do you split a json and send it to kafka bit by bit at an interval? Must be a way to use the `split` in unix command, right

Comment: i meant something like this (ingestion of the tazi data into kafka) https://www.adaltas.com/en/2019/04/18/spark-streaming-data-pipelines-with-structured-streaming/

Comment: so, spark-producer --> kafka message producer --> spark-processing ? Didn't know that was possible.. makes me wonder why we need kafka in the first place ;P

Comment: No..no.. what I am telling is read file using spark , transform that data as per your need and send that data to Kafka.. in this case you are sending data to kafka using spark..you can call this as producer.

Comment: i see, didn't know that. but would it be reasonable or even possible to open a large file, like 10GB, and process it? even the way I am doing it right now is incorrect for going through a large file

Comment: Yes, spark will process big files.. 10 GB is very less.. we are using spark to process TB of data.

Comment: just saw this.. if possible,could you share a link/code snippet/term to google for to preprocess json using spark and sending it to kafka? I can't find it..

Comment: sure, I will share.

Comment: @Srinivas So you use spark to transform data and send to kafka ? That's interesting. Any links/github for it? I am in the same boat as jokl

Comment: No.. you can directly use dataframe and convert data of type string and column name as value then use format as Kafka to send messages

Comment: updated code check for spark batch & streaming sending messages to kafka.

Comment: thanks @Srinivas ! I am trying it right now. I actually had a followup to this which I posted here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499604/processing-data-on-spark-structured-streaming-before-outputting-to-the-console. 
if you have the time :)