# Processing Data on Spark Structured Streaming before outputting to the console

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I'll try to keep it simple.
I periodically read some data from a kafka producer and output the following using Spark Structured streaming

I have data that outputs like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|window                                    |timestamp          |Online_Emp    |Available_Emp    |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|[2017-12-31 16:01:00, 2017-12-31 16:02:00]|2017-12-31 16:01:27|1             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:00:00, 2017-12-31 16:01:00]|2017-12-31 16:00:41|1             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:01:00, 2017-12-31 16:02:00]|2017-12-31 16:01:29|1             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:01:00, 2017-12-31 16:02:00]|2017-12-31 16:01:20|1             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:01:00, 2017-12-31 16:02:00]|2017-12-31 16:01:23|2             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:00:00, 2017-12-31 16:01:00]|2017-12-31 16:00:52|1             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:01:00, 2017-12-31 16:02:00]|2017-12-31 16:01:08|1             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:01:00, 2017-12-31 16:02:00]|2017-12-31 16:01:12|1             |0                |
|[2017-12-31 16:00:00, 2017-12-31 16:01:00]|2017-12-31 16:00:02|1             |1                |
|[2017-12-31 16:00:00, 2017-12-31 16:01:00]|2017-12-31 16:00:11|1             |0                |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

And I want it to output like this:

```
Time         Online_Emp Available_Emp
2017-01-01 00:00:00  52  23
2017-01-01 00:01:00  58  19
2017-01-01 00:02:00  65  28
```

So basically it counts the employees online per minute (through their unique driver id) and shows how many are available.

> Note that one specific employ id may change between `available` and `on_duty` within the minute and we need the final tally until the end of the minute

### Kafka Prod

```
_producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: 
                         json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
    
    # schedule.every(1).minutes.do(_producer.send(topic_name, value=( json.loads(json.dumps(dataDict))) ) )

    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding="utf16") as f: 

        for item in json_lines.reader(f):
            dataDict.update({'timeStamp':item['timestamp'],
                    'emp_id':item['emp_id'],
                    'on_duty':item['on_duty']})
            _producer.send(topic_name, value=( json.loads(json.dumps(dataDict))) )
            sleep(1)
```

### Spark Structured streaming

```
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("timeStamp", LongType()), \
    StructField("emp_id", LongType()), \
    StructField("on_duty", LongType())])

df = spark\
    .readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
    .option("subscribe","emp_dstream")\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
    .load()\
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")\
    .select(F.from_json(F.col("value"), schema).alias("value"))\
    .select(F.col("value.*"))\
    .withColumn("timestamp",F.from_unixtime(F.col("timestamp") / 1000))\
    .groupBy(F.window(F.col("timestamp"), "1 minutes"), F.col("timestamp"))\
    .agg(F.count(F.col("timeStamp")).alias("total_employees"),F.collect_list(F.col("on_duty")).alias("on_duty"),F.sum(F.when(F.col("on_duty") == 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))).alias("not_on_duty"))\
    .writeStream\
    .format("console")\
    .outputMode("complete")\
    .option("truncate", "false")\
    .start()\
    .awaitTermination()
```

How do I get the desired output?

Would be grateful for any hints or help!

Comment: Change this .outputMode("complete") to .outputMode("update") & check if you are getting excepted output ??

Comment: that displays the new output in a separate table but it is still messy. The idea is to club together the same minute time frames into one result (for ex, just one entry for 16:00 - 16:01)

Comment: At 10:01 in Kafka 10 records are available.. spark will read those records and it will aggregate for that minute.. if you get same timestamp data at 10:10 this data will be treated as new data and it will fall into another batch...hence in your final data there will be multiple records..check for more into window function in spark streaming..

Comment: thanks. yes i understand that but i am trying to bucket all in the same minute in one row. Maybe if I change my timestamp to ignore seconds? Could that be don?

Comment: Check there is one more window function which take 3 params..last parameter to define how late your data to consider in current group or batch.

Comment: So i looked it up. You mean reducebywindow? Got this error while using it `AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'reduceByWindow'`

Comment: this one - def window(timeColumn: Column, windowDuration: String, slideDuration: String): Column

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfect. Please check below kafka data & spark streaming output.

`Batch 5`  is your final result and ignore other batches like Batch 0 to 4. Always consider latest batch has updated records as of data available in kafka.

**Batch: 0**

```
No data in kafka.

Spark Streaming
+------+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|window|timestamp|total_employees|on_duty|not_on_duty|
+------+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
+------+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
```

**Batch: 1**

```
Published to kafka.

{"timeStamp": 1592669691475, "emp_id": 12471114, "on_duty": 0} //2020-06-20T21:44:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669691475, "emp_id": 12471124, "on_duty": 0} //2020-06-20T21:44:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669691475, "emp_id": 12471134, "on_duty": 0} //2020-06-20T21:44:51

Spark Streaming
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------+-----------+
|window                                       |timestamp          |total_employees|on_duty  |not_on_duty|
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------+-----------+
|[2020-06-20 21:44:00.0,2020-06-20 21:45:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:44:51|3              |[0, 0, 0]|3          |
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------+-----------+
```

**Batch: 2**

```
Published to kafka.
{"timeStamp": 1592669691475, "emp_id": 12471144, "on_duty": 0} //2020-06-20T21:44:51 // seconds difference
{"timeStamp": 1592669691575, "emp_id": 12471124, "on_duty": 0} //2020-06-20T21:44:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669691575, "emp_id": 12471234, "on_duty": 0} //2020-06-20T21:44:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669691575, "emp_id": 12471334, "on_duty": 1} //2020-06-20T21:44:51

Spark Streaming
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+
|window                                       |timestamp          |total_employees|on_duty              |not_on_duty|
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+
|[2020-06-20 21:44:00.0,2020-06-20 21:45:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:44:51|7              |[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]|6          |
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

**Batch: 3**

```
Published to kafka.
{"timeStamp": 1592669691575, "emp_id": 12471124, "on_duty": 0} // 2020-06-20T21:44:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669691575, "emp_id": 12471424, "on_duty": 1} // 2020-06-20T21:44:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12472188, "on_duty": 1} // 2020-06-20T21:43:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12472288, "on_duty": 0} // 2020-06-20T21:43:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12472388, "on_duty": 0} // 2020-06-20T21:43:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12472488, "on_duty": 1} // 2020-06-20T21:43:51

Spark Streaming
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|window                                       |timestamp          |total_employees|on_duty                    |not_on_duty|
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|[2020-06-20 21:44:00.0,2020-06-20 21:45:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:44:51|9              |[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]|7          |
|[2020-06-20 21:43:00.0,2020-06-20 21:44:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:43:51|4              |[1, 0, 0, 1]               |2          |
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

**Batch: 4**

```
Published to kafka.
{"timeStamp": 1592669691575, "emp_id": 12471524, "on_duty": 0} // 2020-06-20T21:44:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669691575, "emp_id": 12471624, "on_duty": 0} // 2020-06-20T21:44:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12471188, "on_duty": 1} // 2020-06-20T21:43:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12472288, "on_duty": 0} // 2020-06-20T21:43:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12473388, "on_duty": 0} // 2020-06-20T21:43:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12474488, "on_duty": 1} // 2020-06-20T21:43:51

Spark Streaming
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
|window                                       |timestamp          |total_employees|on_duty                          |not_on_duty|
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
|[2020-06-20 21:44:00.0,2020-06-20 21:45:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:44:51|11             |[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]|9          |
|[2020-06-20 21:43:00.0,2020-06-20 21:44:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:43:51|8              |[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]         |4          |
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
```

**Batch: 5**

```
Published to kafka.
{"timeStamp": 1592669571475, "emp_id": 12482185, "on_duty": 1} // 2020-06-20T21:42:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669571475, "emp_id": 12483185, "on_duty": 1} // 2020-06-20T21:42:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669631475, "emp_id": 12484488, "on_duty": 1} // 2020-06-20T21:43:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669691575, "emp_id": 12491524, "on_duty": 0} // 2020-06-20T21:44:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669091575, "emp_id": 12491124, "on_duty": 0} // 2020-06-20T21:34:51
{"timeStamp": 1592669091575, "emp_id": 12491224, "on_duty": 1} // 2020-06-20T21:34:51

Spark Streaming
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------------+-----------+
|window                                       |timestamp          |total_employees|on_duty                             |not_on_duty|
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------------+-----------+
|[2020-06-20 21:34:00.0,2020-06-20 21:35:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:34:51|2              |[0, 1]                              |1          |
|[2020-06-20 21:42:00.0,2020-06-20 21:43:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:42:51|2              |[1, 1]                              |0          |
|[2020-06-20 21:44:00.0,2020-06-20 21:45:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:44:51|12             |[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]|10         |
|[2020-06-20 21:43:00.0,2020-06-20 21:44:00.0]|2020-06-20 21:43:51|9              |[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]         |4          |
+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------------+-----------+
```